# How to store the output of batch (CALL) command to a variable

Tags: shell, batch-file, command, command-prompt

I have the batch file which has the command to call `second.bat` file. It will produce single line of output when it called. I want to store that line into variable.

```
CALL second.bat
```

I have tried using the following lines of commands but no use

```
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN ('COMMAND') do SET result=%%F
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims= " %%A IN ('COMMAND') DO SET NumDocs=%%A
```

I don't know what to replace with `COMMAND`

Answer (score 4):

As the help will tell you, `COMMAND` should be the command you want to run and get the output of. So in your case `second.bat`. At least it works for me:

```
@echo off
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%F IN ('second.bat') do SET result=%%F
echo %result%
```

Note that you cannot use the `usebackq` option if you're using `'` to delimit your command.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr**

To complement [Joey's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12729241/45375) (which fixes the problem with your *1st* command) with a fixed version of both your commands:

```
::  'usebackq' requires enclosing the command in `...` (back quotes aka backticks)
FOR /F "tokens=* usebackq" %%F IN (`second.bat`) do SET result=%%F

:: No characters must follow "delims="; 'tokens=1' is redundant
FOR /F "delims="           %%F IN ('second.bat') DO SET result=%%F
```

Note that in this case there's no need for `call` in order to invoke `second.bat` (which you normally need in order to continue execution of the calling batch file), because any command inside `(...)` is run in a *child* `cmd.exe` process.

---

The only thing needed to make your *2nd* command work is to *remove the space after `delims=`*:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=" %%F IN ('second.bat') DO SET result=%%F
```

**`delims=`** - i.e., specifying *no* delimiters (separators) - **must be placed *at the very end* of the options string**, because the very next character is invariably interpreted as a delimiter, which is what happened in your case: a *space* became the delimiter.

Also, you can *simplify* the command by removing `tokens=1`, because **with `delims=` you *by definition* only get 1 token (per line)**, namely the entire input (line), as-is:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%F IN ('second.bat') DO SET result=%%F
```

Finally, it's worth noting that there's a **subtle difference between `tokens=*` and `delims=`**:

- `delims=` (at the very end of the options string) returns the input / each input line *as-is*.
- `tokens=*` *strips leading delimiter instances* from the input; with the default set of delimiters - tabs and spaces - *leading whitespace* is trimmed.