# i want to store the output of the below command in a variable in batch file

Tags: batch-file

i want to store the output of the below command in a variable in batch file

wmic product where name="%INPUT%" call uninstall

after whether the output matches No Instance(s) Available. then i want to display your input is wrong please check your input

If the condition fails i want to display The product you selected is successfully uninstalled

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12729241/2152082) should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('wmic product where name="%INPUT%" call uninstall') do set output=%%i
if "%output%"=="No Instance(s) Available." (
 echo Your input is incorrect
 goto :skip
)
echo The product you selected was successfully uninstalled
:skip
pause
```

Havn't tested it, as I'm not at my computer.

Comment: @SomethingDark I need one more If any error occur while uninstall how can i know that .???

Comment: just a note: `wmic` output is in local language. (and sadly, `%errorlevel%` is always zero)